# Prevent polkit from listing users

Tags: polkit

How do I disable output for user list and do auth with current invoking user in policykit? This sick message below compromising security on my server/pc revealing the user names!

```
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  me,,, (me)
 2.  other user
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2):
```